# Neo4j.rb : as_json how to ignore root?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, neo4j.rb

For Active record its working fine

ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false

User.first.as_json

```
=> { "id" => 1, "name" => "Konata Izumi", "age" => 16,
     "created_at" => "2006/08/01", "awesome" => true}
```

When I use it for Neo4j.rb active node

Person.first.as_json

```
=> {"person"=> {" first_name"=>"Kay", "last_name" => "Wood",
    "email" => "wood.kay@kozey.co" } }
```

This how I am going to send repsosne by API, I don't need this root element Any help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [neo4j](http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/8.0.x/Configuration.html?highlight=json) documentation :

> include_root_in_json
>
> When serializing ActiveNode and ActiveRel
> objects, should there be a root in the JSON of the model name.
>
> Default: true

So you could just add

```
config.neo4j.include_root_in_json = false
```

in `config/application.rb`.